# Parallel operations in R

Tags: r, multithreading, parallel-processing

Most of the books I've read about R recommend that one try to use "vector operations" like x and y are vectors of equal length:

`x + y`

instead of:

`for (i in 1:length(x)){
    x[i] + y[i]
}`

because x+y is suppose to be faster and walking through a for loop is not.

Why is that? how does this work and make it faster? as far as I can tell, R is only using one process and I can't understand why doing such a thing could be faster.

Comment: Your question is really about 2 things... The vectorized vs looping operations on one hand, and the idea of parrallel-processing on the other. I'd suggest editing it to focus on the first aspect, and making another whole new question about parrallel-processing. It's hard to answer it as it is now (that's why I deleted my answer... but I could undelete it if you really put the focus on vector vs looping).